# Java - get return value of executeScript within thread

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, webview

I'm trying to execute javascript on a WebView and get the output. This works but I'm getting an error when trying to execute this within a thread:

```
@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws InterruptedException {

int x = this.test();
System.out.print(x);
}    



private int test()
{
    return (Integer) engine.executeScript("function x(){return 3}; x();");
}
```

Gives output '3' and doesn't throw an exception, yet when I execute:

```
public void exampleThread() {

    Thread one = new Thread() {
        public void run() {

            while (true) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Does it work?");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);

                    int y = test();

                    System.out.println("Nope: "+y);
                } catch (InterruptedException v) {
                    System.out.println(v);
                }
            }
        }
    };

    one.start();
}
```

It throws:

> Exception in thread "Thread-12" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-12
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:279)
>       at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:423)
>       at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.checkThread(WebEngine.java:1243)
>       at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.executeScript(WebEngine.java:1003)
>       at testApp.FXMLDocumentController.test(FXMLDocumentController.java:91)
>       at testApp.FXMLDocumentController.access$000(FXMLDocumentController.java:28)
>       at testApp.FXMLDocumentController$1.run(FXMLDocumentController.java:76)

Does anybody know what's going on here?

Comment: You can not update the UI on a background thread. I suspect your `test()` method and the JavaScript within it does something to update the UI (is `engine` your `WebView`?).

Comment: I've read about that but strangely enough not. All it does is output it to the console, nowhere does it alter anything of the UI. The code above is pretty much as is.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the WebEngine that is "inside" JavaFX - and it seems to want to run in the JavaFX application thread, which is where you are when executing your event handler in `handleButtonAction()` - but not when you run your own thread.  The simplest solution is just to run your test method in the JavaFX thread (look up `Platform.invokeLater()` ?), or you could probably just hand the script to the JavaScript engine in Java, not the one in JavaFX (which would free you from having to run in the JavaFX application thread...)

Comment: It's Platform.runLater

Comment: Thank you for answer, unfortunately I don't quite understand it. When I run it within the JavaFX function directly I still receive the same error or is that not what you mean?

Comment: I thought you said that your first example (which is the one that runs within the JavaFX handler?) does work ok?